# Extract subsequences from main dataframe based on the locations in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I want to extract the subsequences indicated by the first and last locations in data frame 'B'.
The algorithm that I came up with is:

1. Identify the rows of B that fall in the locations of A
2. Find the relative position of the locations (i.e. shift the locations to make them start from 0)
3. Start a for loop using the relative position as a range to extract the subsequences.

The issue with the above algorithm is runtime. I require an alternative approach to compile the code faster than the existing one.

**Desired output:**

```
first last sequences
  3   5  ACA
  8  12  CGGAG
105 111  ACCCCAA
115 117  TGT
```

**Used data frames:**

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'first.sequence': ['AAACACCCGGAG','ACCACACCCCAAATGTGT'
                   ],'first':[1,100], 'last':[12,117]})

B = pd.DataFrame({'first': [3,8,105,115], 'last':[5,12,111,117]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be as follows:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(B, A, on=['last'], direction='forward',
                    suffixes=('','_y'))

out.loc[:,['first','last']] = \
    out.loc[:,['first','last']].sub(out.first_y, axis=0)

out = out.assign(sequences=out.apply(lambda row: 
          row['first.sequence'][row['first']:row['last']+1], 
          axis=1)).drop(['first.sequence','first_y'], axis=1)

out.update(B)
print(out)

   first  last sequences
0      3     5       ACA
1      8    12     CGGAG
2    105   111   ACCCCAA
3    115   117       TGT
```

**Explanation**

- First, use [`df.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to match `first` values from `B` with `first` values from `A`. I.e. `3, 8` will match with `1`, and `105, 115` will match with `100`. Now we know which string (sequence) needs splitting and we also know where the string starts, e.g. at index `1` or `100` instead of a normal `0`.
- We use this last bit of information to find out where the string slice should start and end. So, we do `out.loc[:,['first','last']].sub(out.first_y, axis=0)`. E.g. we "reset" `3` to `2` (minus 1) and `105` to `5` (minus 100).
- Now, we can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to get the string slices for each sequence, essentially looping over each row. (if your slices would have started and ended at the same indices, we could have used [`Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) instead.
- Finally, we assign the result to `out` (as col `sequences`), drop the cols we no longer need, and we use [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to "reset" the columns `first` and `last`.